# How do I deploy a Windows 7 registry fix using group policy

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

How can I deploy a Windows 7 registry fix using "group policy"?

Comment: Can you define "Windows Registry Fix" a little better?  Is it a .REG file?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Windows 2008 as your domain controller you can use `Group Policy Preferences->Registry` to modify the registry via GP.

Otherwise, you'll probably have to write a startup or log-on script (depending on which key(s) in the registry you need to modify) that applies the fix (look into `reg.exe` for modifying the registry from command batch scripts), and include that script in a GPO that's applied to the systems or users in question.